# Killing a process that is hanging on disk IO

Tags: windows, winapi

I've got an SSD that is failing. Some of its data can't be read anymore.

I would like to know which files are affected.

I've created some small program that uses regular functions (CreateFile, ReadFile) to read files.
The program has some watchdog thread that monitors the thread that issues the IO functions. If they take too long, the thread marks somewhere the file is damaged and tries to kill the IO thread and the process.

My issue is using TerminateThread and TerminateProcess does not kill the thread/process. It hangs there, forever, until I log out.
Trying to kill using TaskManager also fails, of course (it used to use NtTerminateProcess, I don't know what it does nowadays).

Does anyone know a way that would kill my process?

Comment: You can't just kill a process that is waiting for I/O to complete (which seems to be the case here).  [See this old blog from Mark Russinovich](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/unkillable-processes/ba-p/723389): "Because the completion of an I/O request requires access to the address space of the owning thread’s process the system can’t finish tearing down a process until all its I/O requests have completed or cancelled. The I/O Manager has no choice but to wait indefinitely, ...". Read the link for more details/background.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks. Before heading here, I thought "if there's no answer, I think I'll just go read Windows Internals". I recall seeing that chapter with "Notmyfault".

Comment: @Christian.K Could you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [TerminateProcess function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)

> This function stops execution of all threads within the process and
> requests cancellation of all pending I/O. The terminated process
> cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or canceled. When
> a process terminates, its kernel object is not destroyed until all
> processes that have open handles to the process have released those
> handles.
>
> When a process terminates itself, TerminateProcess stops execution of
> the calling thread and does not return. Otherwise, TerminateProcess is
> asynchronous; it initiates termination and returns immediately. If you
> need to be sure the process has terminated, call the
> WaitForSingleObject function with a handle to the process.

I suggest you could try to use [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects).